# How to Typecast a list?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class in third party DLL.

```
Class A
{

}
```

I need to decorate it so I created the local instance of it  and used it

```
class B
{

}
```

The DLL contains a function which gives me the list of A. But If I try to use it as follows

```
B listofB = Dll.FindAllA()
```

I got error that *cannot implicitly convert DLL.A to Proj.B*

There is no difference between the structure of these two classes. How can I convert it?

Comment: Why do you want to make your own class if it's identical to the third party class?

Comment: inherit from A then you can cast it to B later when you need it.

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen : I am creating my own class in a test project where the compiler is suggesting me to add DataServiceEntityAttribute to the class. As I cannot change the code in DLL, I created its replica with DataServiceEntityAttribute attribute.

Comment: ok, so they are "almost" identical classes then ;) I suggest Marc's approach of making a conversion operator between A and B to be your best option then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `A` and `B` don't have anything in common (except they *look* the same), the compiler is out of luck. Options:

- inheritance (sometimes)
- add a conversion operator to either of the types
- add a `ToA` etc extension method if the types are outside of your control
- try automapper
- use serialization (there are ways of making some serializers work with different names etc)

I would go for the first 2 options first. Note that with `List<T>` you can use convert all, i.e.:

```
List<A> orig = ...
List<B> copy = orig.ConvertAll(a => (B)a);// assumes a conversion operator exists
```

For other types, the LINQ `Select` method is equivalent to `ConvertAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you partly gave the answer yourself, because you are talking about 'decorating'. Implement `B` or an descendant of `B` in a way that it decorates an A and wrap the elements of the returned collection in instances of `B`:

```
public class B
{
    // Methods of B
}

public class AToBAdapter : B
{
    A a;

    public AToBAdapter(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    // Override methods of B to map to A
}
```

Now with this adapter in place, you can change the list of As to Bs:

```
B[] listofB = Dll.FindAllA().Select(a => new AToBAdapter(a) as B).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can overload the cast operator on class B:

```
public static implicit operator B(A e)
{
    return new B(e.Property1, e.Property2);
}
```

BTW, you should only use implicit if there can be no data loss and you dont expect an exception, otherwise change to explicit: (B)A

Answer (score 0):

C# is covariant and will not support implicit conversion of collections. Though this issue has been addressed in C#4.0 in a slightly different manner. For example the following code will throw a compile time exception

```
  public class A
  {

  }
   public class B : A
   {

   }

   List<B> obj1 = new List<B>();
   List<A> obj2 = obj1;
```

Though B is derived from A the implicit conversion will not take place. It has to be explicitly converted like below.

```
   List<A> obj2 = obj1.ConvertAll(b => (A)b);
```